# Return result of recursive function

Tags: php

I got a recursive function which currently `echo` the results. I want this function to return results and loop them with `foreach` inside markup.

I understand that i should use some kind of iteration for each array to get my desired result but have failed with that. Currently my code look like this(with attempts to iterate):

```
public static function recursiveChildCategory($categories = array(), $depth = 0, $i = 0) {
    $ca = [];

    // Loop through categories
    foreach($categories as $key => $category){
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth);
        echo "<a href='".implode('/', $category['breadcrumb'])."'>{$category['title']}</a>";
        echo '<br>';

       $ca[$i] = [
           'id' => $category['id'],
           'title' => $category['title'],
       ];

       if(isset($category['child'])) {
           // Loop
           self::recursiveChildCategory($category['child'], $depth + 1, $i++);
       }
   }
   return $ca;
}
```

And incoming array to the function:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 7 
        [title] => Deserts 
        [slug] => deserts 
        [child] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [id] => 8 
                [title] => Space 
                [slug] => space 
                [child] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( 
                        [id] => 
                        [title] => 
                        [slug] => 
                        [child] => Array ( ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Currently it just returns first level of child categories "Deserts", but nothing about "Space".

As desired result i want function to return all categories with `$depth` and infinite path to multiple child categoires (to do the same work as currently `echo` doing).

Thanks in advice

Comment: You are not doing anything with the result of your recursive call: `self::recursiveChildCategory($category['child'], $depth + 1, $i++);`.

Comment: Every time you use your function, you assign an empty array to your `$ca` value and you never use `$depth` (same as `$i`) so try this `recursiveChildCategory($categories = array(), $i = 0, $ca = [])`, remove the `$ca = []` from the function and now do `self::recursiveChildCategory($category['child'], $i++, $ca);`

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I tried multiple variations and this is one of them :\

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the desired output please ?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger As long as you don't use the return value of the recursive call, you will never see anything from the inner array so unless you pass `$ca` by reference, your change will not do anything.

Comment: @jeroen Ofc, that was a comment about his function not an answer about his problem

Comment: @MickaëlLeger Ok, added and edited my function, thanks. Although as you pointed it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and tell me if it's what you are looking for :

**The array for my test** :

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        "id" => 7,
        "title" => "Deserts",
        "slug" => "deserts",
        "child" => [
            0 => [
                "id" => 8,
                "title" => "Space",
                "slug" => "space",
                "child" => [
                    0 => [
                        "id" => 9,
                        "title" => "Test",
                        "slug" => "test"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]    
];
```

**The recursive function** :

```
function recursiveChildCategory($categories, $depth = 0, $ca = []) {
    // Loop through categories
    foreach($categories as $key => $category){
       $ca[$depth] = [
           'id' => $category['id'],
           'title' => $category['title'],
       ];

       if(isset($category['child'])) {
           // Loop
           $ca = recursiveChildCategory($category['child'], $depth + 1, $ca);
       } else {
            break;
       }
   }
   return $ca;
}
```

Now, **how to use it** :

```
$test = recursiveChildCategory($array);
var_dump($test);
```

And this is **the output** :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Deserts"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(8)
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Space"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["title"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
  }
}
```

Here is a link to test it : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

**EDIT** : **I made some modification because in OP example array can have multiple result in first "depth", here is the "new" solution :**

**The array for test :**

```
$array = [ 
    "0" => 
        [ "id" => 3, "title" => "Subcat", "slug" => "subcat", "child" => 
            [ "0" => 
                [ "id" => 5, "title" => "Subsubcat2", "slug" => "subcat2", "child" => 
                    [ "0" =>
                        [ "id" => "", "title" => "", "slug" =>"", "breadcrumb" => [ "0" => "homeworld", "1" => "cat", "2" => "subcat", "3" => "subcat2" ], "child" => [ ] ] 
                    ]
                ] 
            ]
        ],

    "1" => 
        [ "id" => 4, "title" => "Kalahari", "slug" => "kalahari", "child" => 
            [ "0" => [ "id" => 7, "title" => "deserts", "slug" => "deserts", "child" =>
                [ "0" => 
                    [ "id" => 8, "title" => "Ural", "slug" => "ural", "child" => 
                        [ "0" => [ "id" =>"", "title" =>"", "slug" =>"", "child" =>  [ ] ] ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

**The function :** I just add `$ca[$depth][]` instead of `$ca[$depth]`

```
function recursiveChildCategory($categories, $depth = 0, $ca = []) {
    // Loop through categories
    foreach($categories as $key => $category){
       $ca[$depth][] = [
           'id' => $category['id'],
           'title' => $category['title'],
       ];

       if(isset($category['child'])) {
           // Loop
           $ca = recursiveChildCategory($category['child'], $depth + 1, $ca);
       } else {
            break;
       }
   }
   return $ca;
}
```

And now **the result** :

```
$test = recursiveChildCategory($array);

foreach ($test as $depth => $c) {
    echo "depth : ".$depth."\n";
    foreach ($c as $result) {
        echo "Title : ".$result['title']."\n";
    }
     echo "=============\n";
}
```

The **output** is :

```
depth : 0
Title : Subcat
Title : Kalahari
=============
depth : 1
Title : Subsubcat2
Title : deserts
=============
depth : 2
Title : 
Title : Ural
=============
depth : 3
Title : 
=============
```

Test here : [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b02823db2f5c809c027dde4da5304f0d91da7aca)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried function but it still just prints out top of child categories http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b02823db2f5c809c027dde4da5304f0d91da7aca

Comment: In your example your never call the function and the array you use is not the same...it works for me, just if you can have multiple result with same "depth" you can't create a result array as `$c[$depth]` or it will overwrite previous result

Comment: Here is an other example with new solution : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b02823db2f5c809c027dde4da5304f0d91da7aca

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post over here. I come up with this solution and works as expected http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44845645dfd610554193dc479be0e305e1ee20b2 As you pointed me to right direction I'll mark answer as legit. Thanks.